# Shrink and grow canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas
`<canvas id="snakeCanvas" width="350" height="350"></canvas>`
And i would like to constantly shrink and grow the canvas once the users gets a certain score in the game

```js
function Update(){
  if(score >= 10 && score < 30){
    //begin growing and shrinking canvas
  }else if(score >= 30 && score < 50){
    //While still growing and shrinking start rotating canvas slowly clockwise
  }else if(score >= 50){
    //Stop all other animations and begin flipping canvas like a cube
  }
}
```

I know shrinking and growing the canvas can be done as well as probably rotating not sue abt the last one I dont mind using jquery as I am using this code to animate a notice in and out onclick so similar code would be acceptable

```js
$('#notice').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
    $this.animate({
      bottom : '95%'
    }, 500).removeClass('open');
    Game.Notice.notice1.opened = 1;
  } else {
    $this.animate({
      bottom : '70%'
    }, 500).addClass('open');
  }
});
```

Comment: Describe what you mean by "flipping the canvas like a cube". Can you give a link to something doing a similar effect?

Comment: http://movies.flaminggenius.org/ @MatthewKiefer

Comment: Does this help at all? https://jsfiddle.net/wwzqcoyh/

Comment: Ok, last question: In the "cube effect", the other panels of the cube will also be canvas elements? Will the other canvas elements show exactly the same output as the first canvas element?